# How does MVC serialize form data to a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How does MVC set an object's properties from form data?

for example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Method(SomeModel model) <---
{
    ....
}
```

I've tried casting using reflection:

Requirements for this problem must involve creating an object of varying type, from a form's NameValueCollection.

I was trying to cast to a proper object. This works except for when a sub property of the base model is of type Dictionary, KeyValuePair, etc., any other workarounds?

```
    public static object CastFormNew(this NameValueCollection Form, Type type, string FormValueName = null)
    {
        object value = type.DefaultValue();
        try
        {
            if (!type.IsSimple())
            {
                var model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

                foreach (string kvp in Form.AllKeys)
                {
                    PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(kvp, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    if (pi != null)
                    {
                        pi.SetValue(model, Form[kvp], null);
                    }
                }

                value = model;
            }
            else
            {
                var FormValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                Form.CopyTo(FormValues);

                if (FormValues.ContainsKey(FormValueName))
                    value = FormValues[FormValueName];
            }
        }
        catch { }

        return value;
    }
```

model:

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    //Default formats to search for
    public readonly string[] DateTimeFormats =
    {
        "yyyy-MM-dd",
        "MM/dd/yyyy",
        "MM-dd-yyyy"
    };

    [Display(Name = "Date Format")]
    public string DateTimeFormat { get; set; } = "MM/dd/yyyy";

    Dictionary<long, int?> FieldColumnPairs { get; set; }
}
```

form values:

```
 {
    "DateTimeFormat":"MM/dd/yyyy",
    "FieldColumnPairs[0].Key":1,
    "FieldColumnPairs[0].Value":5,
    "FieldColumnPairs[1].Key":2,
    "FieldColumnPairs[1].Value":5,
    "FieldColumnPairs[2].Key":3,
    "FieldColumnPairs[2].Value":5,
 }
```

Actual Results:

```
{
    DateTimeFormat: "MM/dd/yyyy",
    FieldColumnPairs: null
}
```

Expected Results: (from locals in visual studio debugger)

```
{
    DateTimeFormat: "MM/dd/yyyy",
    FieldColumnPairs: Count = 33
    [0]               {[1,5]}
    [1]               {[2,5]}
    [2]               {[3,5]}
    [3]               {[4, ]}
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how it's supposed to work. Check out https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/submitting-a-dictionary-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action

Comment: @RyanTernier I get that, but how do I do the same thing when it's out of the context of the controller? For example, passing the model and the Request to a static method which returns an instance of the model?

Comment: Why would you want to pass raw form data anywhere internally in your code? What's the use case? The whole point of the controller serialising the form data is so that you can then use it as a proper object in your code, and pass that object around between your functions, and be able to do much more with it than a raw request body. Maybe I missed the point but I can't quite work out what you're trying to achieve by (what sounds like) recreating the deserialiser in another part of your application. Why is that useful to you?

Comment: @ADyson The value it provides me is being able to dynamically setup actions for each step in a wizard process. I wanted one class where I can assign actions and the expected model types, rather then implement sloppy multi-variable code for a "wizard" in the controller body.

Comment: Ok but none of that requires you to pass **raw form data** beyond the controller. The controller can still serialise it for you first.

Comment: @ADyson It is required because the action which the form is posted to doesn't have a set model, it only knows type T at runtime.

Comment: It would be better IMO, to have an overarching fixed type which then contains the flexible data (either using generics if possible, or maybe `dynamic` would fit better. But we're drifting off-topic. To actually implement what you're asking for, you might be best to check if that part of MVC which normally does the deserialisation is open-source, and copy it. Or you could switch to sending your form data in JSON format, which would then be trivial to pass in as a string and deserialise later using NewtonSoft.JSON.

Comment: @ADyson which brings me to the topic question, do you have a link to the source of where MVC does this? It would be greatly appreciated, JSON doesn't work for complex collection types so I think I might fallback to dynamic and cast to T at runtime. Thanks for your input!

Comment: No I don't off the top of my head. you'd have to search online to find the right place in the .net GitHub repos. P.s. why on earth wouldn't JSON work for complex collection types? If you can't represent something with JSON then you would not be able to represent it with form-encoded data either. I'm not sure where you've got that idea from. Can you give an example of data which you need in your app but you're unable to represent using JSON?